# Spring Boot Login 401 unauthorized Postman

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, jwt, http-status-code-401

In my spring boot application I have one endpoint for login and one for signup. When signing up everything is fine, the new user is created correctly.
Then if I try to login with the just-created credentials, Postman returns a 401 Unauthorized error. These are my controller methods (first login then signup):

```
@PostMapping(PathConstants.LOGIN_ACTION)
    @ApiOperation("Login into Helios administrational console.")
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<?> autenticate(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest request) {
        System.out.println("Login");
        System.out.println("Us psw " + request.getUsername() + "   " + request.getPassword());
        Authentication auth = authManager
                .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.getUsername(), request.getPassword()));
        System.out.println("Auth " + auth.toString());
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        String token = jwtProvider.generateToken(auth);
        System.out.println("TOken " + token);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtAuthResponse(token));
    }



    @PostMapping(PathConstants.SIGNUP_ACTION)
    @ApiOperation("Signup to Helios administrational console.")
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<?> register(@Valid @RequestBody SignUpRequest request) {
        sysdataUserService.createNewSysdataUser(request);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(new DashboardResponse(true, "New sysdata user registered successfully."));
    }
```

I get on console "login" and "Us psw" with the correct data, but after

```
Authentication auth = authManager
                .authenticate(...)
```

nothing is printed. I'm thinking is a problem with the `authenticate` method, but what problem could be? And how can I solve it? These are my security configurations:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, PathConstants.USER_AUTH +"/**", PathConstants.HELIOS+"/dashboard/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/"+PathConstants.PROCESS_DEFINITION+"/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/"+PathConstants.PROCESS_DEFINITION+"/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/"+PathConstants.PROCESS_INSTANCE+"/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,  PathConstants.LOGIN_ACTION).permitAll()
                //.anyRequest().authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthEntryPoint).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        // custom jwt filter.
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

I've added   `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,  PathConstants.LOGIN_ACTION).permitAll()` to try if this way it works, but still I had 401. Then I have these WebMvcConfigurations for Cors policy:

```
@Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("HEAD", "OPTIONS", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE")
                .allowedHeaders("Content-Type", "X-Requested-With", "accept", "Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method",
                        "Access-Control-Request-Headers")
                .exposedHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials").maxAge(MAX_AGE);
                //.allowCredentials(true).maxAge(MAX_AGE);
    }
```

What is wrong?
All the other endpoints work correctly, but not login.

Comment: did you specifiy the password encoder?

Comment: You can try setting the Spring Security logger level to DEBUG to get more information about the 401 response. Add this to your application.properties file :  logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG

Comment: Where's your AuthenticationManager coming from?